# Obtener JSON compuesto por arrays con Retrofit 2 y Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio y quiero consumir una API de recetas de cocina, tengo la siguiente respuesta de la API que estoy consumiendo con Android Studio y Java:

```
    {
  "q" : "pollo",
  "from" : 0,
  "to" : 10,
  "params" : {
    "sane" : [ ],
    "q" : [ "pollo" ],
    "app_id" : [ "02" ],
    "app_key" : [ "\n66b" ]
  },
  "more" : true,
  "count" : 1000,
  "hits" : [ {
    "recipe" : {
      "uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_d56f75c72ab67a45174441af1efe4473",
      "label" : "Pollo con Crema a las Hierbas",
      "image" : "http://cdn.kiwilimon.com/recetaimagen/23127/thumb120x90-15802.jpg",
      "source" : "KiwiLimon",
      "url" : "http://www.kiwilimon.com/receta/carnes-y-aves/pollo-con-crema-a-las-hierbas",
      "shareAs" : "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/pollo-con-crema-a-las-hierbas-d56f75c72ab67a45174441af1efe4473/pollo",
      "yield" : 42.0,
```

Y continua con mas 'recipe', lo que quiero es obtener solo el array de hits que tiene todas las recetas para poder mostrar en mi aplicación, el problema es que me da el siguiente error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Entiendo que es porque espera un array y obtiene un objeto JSON, pero no se como parsearlo, tengo mi clase modelo Recipe y el servicio RecipeService y lo manejo todo en la MainActivity, he visto en algunas respuestas que tendria que hacer una respuesta intermedia, pero no entiendo como lo podría implementar en mi código, a continuación muestro las clases que manejan todo esto.

Recipe:

```
public class Recipe {
    private String label;
    private String image;
    private String source;
    private String shareAs;
    private List<String> dietLabels;
    private List<String> healthLabels;
    private List<String> cautions;
    private List<String> ingredientLines;
    private List<String> ingredients;
    private double calories;
    private double totalWeight;
    private List<String> totalNutrients;
    private List<String> totalDaily;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

RecipeService:

```
    public interface RecipeService {

    String API_ROUTE = "/search";
    String API_KEY = "&app_key=" + Credentials.API_KEY;
    String APP_ID = "&app_id=" + Credentials.APP_ID;
    //String query = "";

    @GET(API_ROUTE)
    Call< List<Recipe> > getRecipe(@Query("q") String q);

}
```

MainActivity:

```
 private void getRecipes() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("https://test-es.edamam.com")
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

        RecipeService recipeService = retrofit.create(RecipeService.class);
        Call<List<Recipe>> call = recipeService.getRecipe("pollo");

        System.out.println("GET RECIPES");
        System.out.println("HEADERS: "+ call.request().headers());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Recipe>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Response<List<Recipe>> response) {

                System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE: " + response.code());
                for(Recipe recipe : response.body()){

                    System.out.println("AÑADIENDO: " + recipe.getLabel());
                    recipes.add(recipe.getLabel());
                }
                //System.out.println(recipes.toArray().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("HA OCURRIDO UN FALLO");
                System.out.println(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si sigues teniendo la falla, te recomendaria instalar la extension RoboPOJOGenerator de Android Studio, ahi solo pegas tu json de la respuesta y ya te genera automaticamente el modelo o modelos necesarios.

Por lo que veo, el problema estaria en que tienes que tener un modelo Principal donde se encuentran estos datos de tu json:

```
  {
  "q" : "pollo",
  "from" : 0,
  "to" : 10,
  "params" : {
    "sane" : [ ],
    "q" : [ "pollo" ],
    "app_id" : [ "02" ],
    "app_key" : [ "\n66b" ]
```

Posteriormente tienes una llave "hits" entonces requieres un modelo Hits el cual deberia de contener un List y entonces ya viene el modelo Recipes asi si quieres obtener todos los Recipes necesitas un metodo dentro del modelo Hits.

Por lo anterior, te recomiendo RoboPOJOGenerator el cual ya te genera todos los modelos necesarios.